# Google Cloud SSLHandshakeError

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python

We are trying to download reviews ratings and stats data of mobile apps from google cloud.

In the server machine a ubuntu box, I installed gcloud. I did authentication in the box with using `gcloud auth` command. 
I am using following code to get the bucket

```
client = storage.Client(cfg.get('google-play','client'))
bucket = client.get_bucket(cfg.get('google-play','bucket'))
```

sometime the get_bucket is throwing following exception. Most of the time it works fine

```
File "google-crashes-anrs-api/DailyDownloadAndInsert.py", line 76, in <module>
    bucket = client.get_bucket(cfg.get('google-play','bucket'))
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/storage/client.py", line 167, in get_bucket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 77, in reload
    _target_object=self)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 343, in api_request
    target_object=_target_object)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 241, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 270, in _do_request
    body=data)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 153, in new_request
    credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 765, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 797, in _do_refresh_request
    self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/apps/mnstools/apps/.virtualenvs/google-crashes-anr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1059, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Can anyone please help if I am missing any configuration. I am clueless coz sometime it works and it fails sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably problems with openssl installation. Check you have up to date openssl installed and try the newest `google-cloud-storage` package. If it still fails, try ot from different machine or virtualenv with a fresh newest packages.